# Multiple Outputs From One Set of Labels

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, label

I am building a website in ASP.NET Web Forms with a SQL Database. The database contains a table with 571 entry's of data.

**Output**

[image]

**Source Code**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built FROM Houses ORDER BY Name DESC", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                                lblId.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                                lblName.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                                lblTown.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                                lblNear.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                                lblStatus.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                                lblBuilt.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Database**

[image]

I want to display all 571 houses to do this I would need a set of labels for each house but is there a way I could have one set of labels like the above code to output all 571 entry's without repeating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a Repeater. This is a special control, which allows to define an inner item layout only once and then bind some data to render multiple blocks looking consistently, but containing the different data.

[Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has ItemTempalte property, which allows you to wrap all the labels you want to see.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then just load the DB rows into repeater:

```
rptData.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
rptData.DataBind();
```

And finally, in the HTML layout specify mapping for labels to respective columns - like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Townland") %>'></asp:Label>
```

etc.